# Why do some applications return if already running, and otherwise block?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, application-launch

When using a command line to open multiple tabs in a GUI application, often the first command blocks (waiting until the application is closed) but the subsequent commands each return immediately (while the application is still running). How does this work?

I've noticed this when using bash to open different successive files in a text editor (with a commands such as `gedit file3.txt` or `spyder file7.txt`), or similarly when using a web browser (with `xdg-open file2.html`). I assume the subsequent commands get passed somehow to the existing process, rather than spawning additional processes?

Often if I want to edit multiple files, I might work-around this behaviour by explicitly running the first-invocation in the background (using `&` or `bg`), before running each subsequent invocation in the foreground, and avoiding closing and reopening the application. How can I control whether my own (or someone else's) application behaves in this way?

Comment: Single instancing an application is done through a mutex.  Mutexes are managed by the kernel and are system wide mechanism to protect shared resources. Typically.. when an application starts, it will check to see if a particular mutex is set.  If it isn't, it will make one and startup.. if it is, it will just exit.  I am not sure about Linux.. but I could pull some of what you are talking about in Win32 (which I know better).  I assume that Liinux would have the same.  Lookup MUTEX..

Comment: Oh.. in the case you mention above.. gedit opens.. it was given a command line.. it checks for it's mutex to see if another instance is running.  If it is.. there are MANY ways for gedit to "pass the command line" to the running instance.. subprocess.. signalling.. mapped file.. named pipe.. and MORE! Each application uses its own method to determine how to do inter-process communication.

Answer (score 1):

When you start `gedit`, it first checks if `gedit` is already running. If it's not, it proceeds to open the file. Otherwise, it signals the older process to open a file in a new tab and quits.

Comment: How does it check and how does it signal? (For example, can it be tricked?) Do most applications use the same mechanism, or does each one implement it uniquely?

Comment: @benjimin Do you want me to analyze each and every single application that does this and make a comparison? ;) Your question is generic, my answer is generic. If you're interested in a particular implementation, if it's an open source one, I encourage you to take a look at the code and figure it out yourself. With closed source apps you could still figure it out using for example gdb or maybe even strace, but it will require some skill.